# $x \mapsto x^n $ is a automorphism of group $G$, show that for all $x$ in $G$, $x^{n-1} \in Z(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> If $x \mapsto x^n $  is a automorphism of group $G$, show that for all
>   $x$ in $G$, $x^{n-1} \in Z(G)$.

This mean $G=\{x^n:x \in G\}$ and $x^n=e$ if and only if $x= e$.

Now let $y\in G$. I Want to show that $$yx^{n-1}=x^{n-1}y.$$
We know that $y$ is $n^{\text {th}}$ power of some element of $G$, but how to proceed from here?

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that if $x\mapsto x^n$ is an automorphism, then applying that map twice gives the identity map.

Comment: @Arthur how does that help ?

Comment: Because that means that some elements are sent to their inverses, and some elements are sent to themselves. The subgroup of elements sent to their inverse is in the center and the subgroup of elements sent to themselves means $x^{n-1}=e$. Every other element is the product of two such elements. Again, I haven't actually checked any of these claims (otherwise I would post it as an answer), but it feels right.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $(yx)^n=y^nx^n$(by  definition of homomorphism). So $$\underbrace{(yx)(yx)\cdots (yx)}_{\text {$n-1$ times}}\;y=y^n x^{n-1}.$$ Now

\begin{align}
y^n x^{n-1}&=x ^{-1}x\;\underbrace{(yx)(yx)\cdots (yx)}_{\text {$n-1$ times}}\;y\\
&=x ^{-1}\underbrace{(xy)(xy)\cdots (xy)}_{\text {$n$ times}}\\
&=x^{-1}(xy)^n\\
&=x^{-1}x^ny^n\, (\text{again by homomorphism definition})\\
&=x^{n-1}y^n.
\end{align}

Comment: Here $x^{n-1}$ commute with $y^n$ , but how we are confirmed that this will commute with all $x \in G$?

Comment: @TheStudent We have to show that $x^{n-1}\in Z(G)$ and for that, it suffices to show that it commutes with $y^n$ because $y\mapsto y^n$ is an automorphism.

Comment: Thank you @Shivering Soldier for your response, i just have one doubt, is this still true ,i group will be of infinite order?

Comment: @TheStudent: I think so. I don't see any finiteness assumption being used.

Answer (score 0):

As $x \mapsto x^n $ is an automorphism, by the homomorphism's condition, we have that $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$ and:

$$\begin{align}
y^nx^{n-1}y^{-n}&=y^nx^{n-1}xx^{-1}y^{-n}\\
&=(yx)^nx^{-1}y^{-1}y^{-n+1}\\
&=(yx)^{n-1}y^{-n+1}\\
&=y^{n-1}x^{n-1}y^{-n+1}\
\end{align}$$

And now:

$$y^nx^{n-1}y^{-n}=y^{n-1}x^{n-1}y^{-n+1} \implies yx^{n-1}y^{-1}=x^{n-1}; x^{n-1} \in Z(G)$$